# Treat generic struct as trait object

Tags: generics, rust

I have a struct with generic T for which I want to create a vector of instances of this struct, where for each instance T can be different. I realise I probably need to use a box and possibly need to treat my struct as a trait object, but I am not sure how, since it is not a collection of different structs which implement the same trait, but instead the same struct with a different generic. Below is what I have so far and hopefully illustrates what I am trying to achive, it doesn't work because the dyn keyword seems to expect a trait rather than a generic struct.

```rust
struct Point<T> {
    x: T,
    y: T,
}

struct Points {
    points: Vec<Box<dyn Point>>,
}
fn main() {
    let points = Points {
        points: vec![Point { x: 1, y: 2 }, Point { x: 1.1, y: 2.2 }],
    };
}
```

Comment: only trait can be dynamic, a dynamic struct don't make sense.

Comment: I suggest you explain of your real problem/need instead of asking help with what you try to solve your need #xyproblem

Comment: If you have the code `let x = points[0].x`, what type (known at compile time) do you expect `x` to be? Please give an example of the code you expect to *use* `points`? What could it do, given that `T` could be a String or a `std::sync::mpsc::channel`? Do you mean that you want to hide `x` and `y` from the users of `points`? (Whatever specific things you want to be able to do with each element of `Point`, you will put into a trait, and then `points` will be a Vec of that trait, not the struct.)

Comment: @RobNapier thanks, that makes sense. If a collection of the same struct is generic then I can't use their data unless I know what the type is, so will need to implement methods for each type used, which means I may as well define those methods as a trait and use trait objects rather than struct instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"The same struct with a different generic" behaves very similarly to "a different struct". Here, when dealing with trait objects, the concrete type doesn't matter, which is the key idea behind a trait object.

For example:

```rust
trait Trait {
  fn foo(&self) -> &'static str;
}

struct Point<T> {
  x: T,
  y: T,
}

// you may have different impls for different generics
impl<T> Trait for Point<T> {
  fn foo(&self) -> &'static str {
    "a point"
  }
}

fn main() {
  let points: Vec<Box<dyn Trait>> = vec![
    Box::new(Point {x: 1, y: 2}),
    Box::new(Point {x: 1.1, y: 2.2}),
    Box::new(Point {x: (), y: ()}),
  ];

  for point in points {
    println!("{}", point.foo());
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you! I suspected that adding a trait like this would be necessary, but wan't sure if there was another way because it seems weird and redundant to and a method to a struct even if you don't need it, just so it can be treated as a trait object.

Comment: Don't use `box_syntax`, [it's something the Rust team would like to remove](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/49733). Provides no benefit over `Box::new()`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that about `box_syntax`, I'll edit it out. Personally I've used it in small projects just because it's quicker to type, but agreed it provides little else over that.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the points in an `enum`:

```rust
struct Point<T> {
    x: T,
    y: T,
}

struct Points {
    points: Vec<PointType>,
}

enum PointType {
    U64(Point<u64>),
    F32(Point<f32>),
}

fn main() {
    let points = Points {
        points: vec![
            PointType::U64(Point { x: 1, y: 2 }),
            PointType::F32(Point { x: 1.1, y: 2.2 }),
        ],
    };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5a4a3e52653cd52f109c0ce8565a084e)